# Unable to kill process with PID 1 in docker container

Tags: debian, process, docker, kill

I have the following Dockerfile for creating a container with a powerdns recursor in it:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    pdns-recursor && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean
COPY ./configuration/recursor.conf /etc/powerdns/recursor.conf
RUN chown -R :pdns /etc/powerdns/ && \
    chmod 0750 /etc/powerdns/ && \
    chmod 0640 /etc/powerdns/recursor.conf
EXPOSE 8699
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/pdns_recursor", "--daemon=no"]
```

My `recursor.conf` looks like this:

```
config-dir=/etc/powerdns
forward-zones=resolver1.opendns.com=208.67.222.222
hint-file=/usr/share/dns/root.hints
local-address=0.0.0.0
local-port=8699
quiet=yes
security-poll-suffix=
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
```

IPv6 is disabled on the hypervisor.

The problem is that docker is not able to stop the container properly with `docker stop recursor`. After some time the OOMKiller terminates the programm with the following information:

```
Exited (137) 2 seconds ago
```

I searched the web and the signals `128` + `9` = `137` mean that I don't have sufficient RAM, what is simply not the case. When I execute `docker exec -it recursor /bin/bash` and try to kill PID 1 (`kill -9 -- 1`) within the container I don't get any reaction - the service simply continues to run as if nothing happened.

I also tried to start the recursor in daemon-mode - same result.

Does anyone has an idea why that is so?

Comment: You can find a way here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088261/restarting-an-unhealthy-docker-container-based-on-healthcheck

Answer (score 28):

Process with PID 1 is the init process. That stays true in a pid namespace or a container: this pid 1 cannot be killed with `SIGKILL` because it has no `KILL` signal handler defined, contrary to *any* other userland process.

If you really want to kill it, you have to kill it *from the host*. Running on the host (with enough privileges, probably root):

```
kill -KILL $(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername)
```

This will bring down the whole container since removing its PID 1 means stopping the container. Please note that I answered to the title of the question, but not to the underlying problem: what is causing OOM.

UPDATE: probably simplier to use [`docker kill`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/), which defaults to the `KILL` signal. That would be:

```
docker kill containername
```

UPDATE2: convince that PID 1 cannot be killed with `SIGKILL` (aka `-9`), *even* in a container (the example requires user namespace enabled else just use `unshare --mount-proc --fork --pid` as root).

first terminal:

```
$ unshare --map-root-user --mount-proc --fork --pid
# echo $$
1
# pstree -p
bash(1)---pstree(88)
# kill -9 1
#
```

no effect

On a second terminal:

```
$ pstree -p $(pidof unshare)
unshare(2023)───bash(2024)
$ kill -9 2024
```

first terminal:

```
# Killed
$
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would not agree to that. I can kill other containers being IN the container issuing `kill -- 1` (PID 1) and they stop immediately. Also when I issue `docker stop container` from outside they stop immediately. I know about the rough `docker kill container` and I know that I can kill him from the host using his PID, but that's not the crux of this matter.

Comment: you said kill -9 -- 1 . Try it inside a container: specifically with the -9 signal. Those that behave correctly can be killed with any other intended signal (eg -15 / -TERM, the default or for a real init process (not an app), -2 / -INT), either because they don't intercept it (and get the death behaviour), either because they intercept it but behave correctly.

Comment: yes, you were right, `-9` does not work for PID 1. But I still need to figure out, why I get `Exited (137)` with a normal `docker stop` :)

Comment: Clean way to get host pid of container pid 1: `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' containername`

Comment: @mviereck thanks, changed my answer accordingly

Comment: If container runs with init system `tini` (docker option `--init`), it works to do `kill 1` in container. `--init` fails on some systems, compare: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/issues/23#issuecomment-386817295

Comment: @mviereck again the only non-working case is `kill -9 1` (as is stated in the question) with the KILL signal (which doesn't have an handler installed, *only* for PID 1)

Comment: @A.B ok, thanks for clarification! Just tested it, `kill -9 1` fails with `tini`, too.

Comment: @mviereck use case is when process 1 is directly the application (httpd , powerdns etc.) so when a bug prevents it to react to any usual signal because it intercepted them (HUP, TERM, ...) one would think KILL would do it since non-interceptable. Except it isn't set at all for process 1 (probably the same with the STOP signal etc.) hence the need to kill it from outside

Comment: @A.B: One possibility is left within container: If running with `tini` as container init system, it is possible to send `KILL` to its child processes. `tini` terminates if its children are gone.